# SSH into router (extender; tplink) running linux 2.6

Tags: linux, router, ssh, openssh, ssh-keys

I have a TP Link Extender that I can access over the http server login page on port 80, and there is a an open ssh port on 22. I can ssh into the server, it asks for the password that I type in. Then it says "shell request failed on channel 0" and tty failed on Ch 0. Now I found out that the ssh is only allowing the tp link tether app to access the server. I have all credentials, but it won't allow me to login with the terminal, only through the app wich connects through ssh. This app has only specific options not these I need as I want to modify the Linux 2.6 on the extender. I want to change the mac address of the extender via ifconfig. . Is there a way to extract the key or whatever from the app and then spoof it with my os to bypass the client restriction? (Extender is mine I have all data, as password is accepted but not the client) . Can I somehow differently bypass avoid the shell and tty request error and send linux commands to the Linux on extender? . Can I somehow route my commands through the app by extracting apk tp link tether app and import my commands and or where should I search for the app loging into ssh of extender part? . Any other suggestions? Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: I wonder if she is actually available to the application either, or if it is interacting via scp or sftp (which use the SSH protocol but not tty. What is the model of the extender?

Comment: Im not sure but makes sense. The model is -> TL-WA850RE

Comment: i tried connection with scp or sftp through 22 couldnt create shell. it accepts every username but only the right password btw

Comment: Not sure how to fix the problem with the TP-Link firmware, but it's [supported](https://openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wa850re) for OpenWRT. So another option is installing OpenWRT, and then you can configure it to your heart's content. And yes, you can flash it back if you have an image of the old firmware.

Comment: I agree with dirkt, use openwrt if you want to customize. Messing with the kernel of the stock firmware isn't a great idea anyway. You can brick it or send it into an unrecoverable boot loop.

Comment: ok guys. so OpenWRT really seems to be the right way to go thank your for that. Im afraid that this Software is not available for my Hardware. i have the V4 and only V2 and 1 are supported. I tried to flash it but it gets a signature error. Probably because of the hardware version. maybe good because i couldve soft bricked my device. is there a way to adjust it on my own? ( i mean OpenWRT, like kinda rewrite it or something like that.)